# ipconfig /release (AUTO RENEW???)

Tags: networking, windows-10, wireless-networking, ip, dhcp

I have a (very very) remote machine running over teamviewer, I (mistakenly) ran

```
ipconfig /release
```

The machine is set never to sleep or restart and no items are set to power saving mode. The only event that will occur is that one device connected via Ethernet (a Westermo MRD-355) will reboot at 1am every day. Will this likely be enough to renew all DHCP licenses? At present I have no connection to the device as the release has meant I have lost network communication with wifi and with the modem.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Make sure your passport is up-to-date, and get a plane ticket to wherever that remote computer is - you're going to need to either manually reboot the sucker, or at the very least issue a IPCONFIG/RENEW from the keyboard...

Comment: I once saw one of the best technicians I have ever known make the same mistake, so you are in good company.  Thankfully, he only needed to drive two hours round-trip to reboot the machine.

Comment: +1 for admitting your mistake...

Comment: So you have absolutely no one at the remote location that can restart the server?

Comment: Or anyone at the remote location that can bring the local power grid down?

Comment: Thank goodness it turned out the modem reboot renewed the licenses!!!